# how to manage huge task for a huge number of users in django

Tags: python, django, architecture, system-design

I have a system developed in django where a lot of calculations have to be done for each user. The process takes almost 5 to 6 seconds for each user to complete the calculations. Currently I am using celery and rabbitmq to run the job as the number of user is limited now.
The upcoming scenario is:

```
 1. The number of users almost 100000
 2. Have run the process at a certain time in each week for all users
 3. Have to complete the total tasks for all the users in a few seconds
```

I am using amazone aws server.
can you please suggest me the archetectural scenario on this.

Comment: interesting to know is if the tasks for each user need to run in parallel or somewhere within that 1-week timespan?

Comment: tasks for each user should start at a certain time lets say 12:01 am on each monday and can execute parallelly @Jonas